# C# XNA - Random Room Generation

Tags: c#, random, xna

```
SetType(type);

        for (int x = (Globals.tileSize + (int)position.X); x < ((int)position.X + (Globals.screenWidth - Globals.tileSize)); x += Globals.tileSize)
        {

            for (int y = (Globals.tileSize + (int)position.Y); y < ((int)position.Y + (Globals.screenHeight - Globals.tileSize)); y += Globals.tileSize)
            {
                tileType = tileFillTypes[random.Next(1, tileFillTypes.Count())];
                Tile tile = new Tile(new Vector2(x, y), tileType, false);
                tiles.Add(tile);
            }
        }
```

Map generation calls this class to draw random tiles in a box.  SetType(type) is called which does this:

```
void SetType(int type)
    {
        if (type == 1) //ROOM TYPE 
        {
            tileWallTypesBottom = new string[] { "", "stonewallBottom1", "stonewallBottom2", "stonewallBottom3" };

            tileFillTypes = new String[] { "" };
        }
        else if (type == 2)
        {
            tileWallTypesBottom = new string[] { "", "stonewallBottom1", "stonewallBottom2", "stonewallBottom3" };
            tileWallTypesLeft = new string[] { "", "stonewallLeft1", "stonewallLeft2", "stonewallLeft3" };
            tileWallTypesRight = new string[] { "", "stonewallRight1", "stonewallRight2", "stonewallRight3" };
            tileWallTypesTop = new string[] { "", "stonewallTop1", "stonewallTop2", "stonewallTop3" };
            tileFillTypes = new String[] { "", "dirt1", "dirt1", "dirt1", "dirt1", "dirt1", "dirt1", "dirt1", "dirt1", "dirt1", "dirt2", "dirtGrassPatch", "dirt4", "dirt4", "dirt4", };
            tileWallCornerType = new string[] { "", "stonewallTopLeft", "stonewallTopRight", "stonewallBottomRight", "stonewallBottomLeft" };

        }

    }
```

This sets my array for which tiles I can pick from randomly.
My problem is when I generate multiple rooms with this code in each instance of room, the rooms don't come out random from eachother.  I've tried setting random = new Random(); in each instance and they always have the same output of tiles.

Comment: Don't create a new **Random** each time as it won't be particularly random. _[Would you like to know more?](http://www.dotnetperls.com/random)_

Answer (score 0):

This resource should explain the cause of your problem and the common solutions:

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Relevant snippet:

> The Random class is not a true random number generator. It's a
>   pseudo-random number generator. Any instance of Random has a certain
>   amount of state, and when you call Next (or NextDouble or NextBytes)
>   it will use that state to return you some data which appears to be
>   random, mutating its internal state accordingly so that on the next
>   call you will get another apparently-random number.
>
> All of this is deterministic. If you start off an instance of Random
>   with the same initial state (which can be provided via a seed) and
>   make the same sequence of method calls on it, you'll get the same
>   results.
>
> So what was wrong in our example code? We were using a new instance of
>   Random on each iteration of the loop. The parameterless constructor
>   for Random takes the current date and time as the seed - and you can
>   generally execute a fair amount of code before the internal timer
>   works out that the current date and time has changed. Therefore we're
>   using the same seed repeatedly - and getting the same results
>   repeatedly.

One Example Solution:

```
// Somewhat better code...
Random rng = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GenerateDigit(rng));
}
...
static int GenerateDigit(Random rng)
{
    // Assume there'd be more logic here really
    return rng.Next(10);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your explanation.  What's wrong with my code?  It's generating the rooms fine and randomly, but then all of the rooms end up the same exact as the first room generated.  How would I 'refresh' the random values?

Comment: Short answer is to avoid making a new Random each time, since that resets it.       Long answer is that Random isn't the best provider of Randomization and that you are better off creating or using a more complex Random Number generation process, which takes a bit of effort and learning.

Comment: @SilasReinagel A fine description regarding **Random** but consider editing it slightly in context for the OP

Comment: No where in my code am I reusing Random.   I call it once initializing it but not in the loop.  Am I blind?  What else should I use to random?

Comment: If you are concerned simply with not getting the same set each time, ensure that you seed the RNG freshly when you instantiate it, like this: Random rng = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());